# Duplicate request WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have implemeted WCF method as below.

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
       [OperationContract]
       string string AddUser(string name,string department,string empCode);
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
            public string AddUser(string name,string department,string empCode)
            {
                UserDAL.LogRequest(name,department,empcode); //Log request in database

                bool isExist=UserDAL.IsExist(name,department,empCode); //Check same user exist or not
                if(isExist==false)
                {
                    UserDAL.Add(name,department,empCode);
                }
            }
    }
```

This WCF is used by .Net winform app, SOAP UI, ORACLE etc. Before inserting user details I have checked that same user not exist in database(ie.UserDAL.IsExist). But still it inserted duplicate records in DB.I have also checked 'UserDAL.IsExist' method and it returned true if same user details exist in DB. I have noticed that duplicate records inserted in fraction of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. Your code is not safe. It will check *and then* insert. What if two people call your service with the same information at the same time?

> Call1: UserDAL.IsExist returns false
>
> Call2: UserDAL.IsExist returns false
>
> Call1: Inserts
>
> Call2: Fails

You need a unit that syncronizes. That should be your database. You should just insert and listen for failures. Why is your database even accepting the insertion of duplicates? You need constraints there.